# Verify success of Azure Resource Mover?

Tags: azure

I am using [Azure Resource Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-virtual-machines) to move a VM between Azure regions.  So far, the VM and its dependencies have all transitioned through the following states:

Prepare pending --> Prepare in progress --> initiate Move pending --> initiate move in progress --> commit move pending --> commit move in progress

And now they are all in the “delete source pending” state.  The [documentation about this step](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2150414) states:

"After committing the move, and verifying resources in the target region, you can delete the source resource."

My question is about “verifying resources in the target region”.  When I click on the individual resources and view their properties, the “location” value is still the old region.  This almost suggests to me that the move didn’t work.  But I’m not sure.  I certainly don’t want to delete the source resources until I can confident they moved properly.  Can anyone advise how to properly "verify" the resources in the target region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out.  If you merely click on your individual resources from within the Resource Mover UI (as I did), you will view the "source" copy of these resources, which of course is still in the source region.  If instead you remember that the Resource Mover created a new Resource Group in your target region, and navigate thither, you will see the new "target" copy of your resources, right where you expect to see them.